# Using an SSIS config file with password in a different location/file

Tags: ssis

I have a single Sybase user account that accesses many db/tables.  I created a config file for each server/db connection I use in my ssis packages.  What i would like to do is store the password for those connections in one place and have the config file access/go get the password at run time.  I'm required to change my password once a year I would like to go to one place to change it instead of all the different config files.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Create one config file that holds the connection strings for all your connections - then set up your packages to look at this one file.  Configuration files can be shared, so you only need to store it in the one place.